# iOS Method with blocks in container class

Tags: ios, design-patterns, restkit, objective-c-blocks

I am looking for some solution that could help me reuse methods that use Restkit. I have these methods in my controller:

```
    RKObjectManager *restManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"somePath"
                       parameters: ... some parameters ...
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         ...
     }
                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         ...
     }];
```

and I want to create some helper class that would contains these methods and give simpler methods. Something like this:

```
- (someResultClass *)getResultsFromSomePath:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

And I would check if in someResultClass are results or it ends with failure. I hope it's clear what I want. I am looking for some solution to move code with RestKit to some container class and just have one line of code instead. I think it could be problem that there are blocks but I hope it solution exists. One more thing, it's not thing that would be needed I am just looking for solution that could make controller class more simple and move more code to other classes.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the thread that calls getResultsFromSomePath: to be blocked until the rest requests are completed and the method returns a value?

Comment: Not to be blocked. It could work like async/await in C#. When it comes to getResultsFromSomePath it would wait (but UI still reacts) and when there would be results it would come back and execute rest of code after that line. I am just looking for something which could make easier to read this when you have for example one restkit method inside success block of another.

Comment: Waiting before executing the remainder is blocking. RestKit is not designed to be blocking. Reconsider what you're trying to do, and embrace the asynchronous nature of it. Then try something, show the code, and explain what it does wrong.